# CodeIgniter - Adding a default value to a form_dropdown from config

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the dropdown values from config files.

Suppose I have the below in config file

```
$config['test']['1'] = 'Test 1';
$config['test']['2'] = 'Test 2';
```

I need to display this in the view using form_dropdown and I need to display '-- Please select --' on top of the list. (by default, '-- Please select --' should be selected)

So, in the dropdown, it should look like this.

```
-- Please select --
Test 1
Test 2
```

To display '-- Please select --' in the dropdown, do I need to add it in the config file like below

```
$config['test']['-1'] = '-- Please select --';
$config['test']['1'] = 'Test 1';
$config['test']['2'] = 'Test 2';
```

or do I need to merge '-- Please select --' to the config array in the php just before using in form_dropdown?

Comment: Both options are acceptable, but i'm for merge option

Comment: I agree with @Armen, but populating a dropdown from a config file is an odd approach imho.